# Overflowing apparatus in eledpar (changing \goalfraction within a pages environment)

Tags: eledmac, eledpar

I have a question regarding the usage of the \goalfraction command of the eledpar package. By default the value of 0.9 works great, but on few pages the apparatus text flows over the bottom of the page.

Just asked myself, if there is a chance to change the goalfraction value within a parallel pages environment? Putting the command in some paragraph or between \pend and \pstart returned no effect. I am very grateful for any help or advice regarding the overflowing apparatus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, changing the \goalfraction between \pend can't work, because the goal fraction retained will be the last defined before \Page. You can try with the optional argument of \pend, it should work for the change.

However, the goal fraction  default values normally work right if you apply adviced explained in the § 4.5.1 of the eledpar handbook, in order to obtain a correct maximal height of notes, and to have notes flowing through pages.

```
\maxhXnotes{0.6\textheight}
\maxhnotesX{0.6\textheight}
```

If there two solutions does not work, please send a MWE (even directly to me by email)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The definition of a maximum height for the notes did the best job for me. Although the \goalfraction in an optional argument had also a good local effect.